# How to link css external file which is stored on Dropbox?

Tags: html, css, dropbox

Not possible link an external CSS file stored in Dropbox with HTML.

Tried and follow up all the instructions I could find online.
That I need to left click and press "Copy Dropbox Link" and that should be by href link but Is not working.

The general dropbox link looks like the the code below
(Changed the ?dl=0 to raw=1 and remove www.dropbox with dl. but  still with no luck).

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  
href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxx/xxx.css">
```

Could you please check and please point out what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: you can use github.

Answer (score 1):

To use this URL in your stylesheet you will need to make a small adjustment to the URL by changing the `www.` in the URL to `dl.`

This allows Docs to access the source of the file rather than the Dropbox page for the file.

Finally, your code like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxx/xxx.css?dl=0">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this and I wish it could work but no...and that's really strange as this is the "indication" made by the Dropbox documentation as well.

Comment: In dropbox have you put all the files in the public folder?

Comment: Yeah all the files are in the public folder

Answer (score -2):

By default, Dropbox links are for sharing, not for embedding in websites. You'll need to modify the link to make it suitable for use in your HTML document.
Replace "www.dropbox.com" with "dl.dropboxusercontent.com" in the URL. This change allows direct file access.